# Transposing arrays Run-time error '9'

Tags: excel, vba

How to correctly transpose the following array? I get Out of Range error when I run the code. The values should populate starting in `B2`.

```
Sub Checkb()
    Dim acat As Variant
    ReDim acat(0)
    Dim contr As Control

    For Each contr In UserForm2.Controls
        If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
            If contr.Value = True Then
                MsgBox (contr.Value)
                acat(UBound(acat)) = contr.Name
                ReDim Preserve acat(UBound(acat) + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve acat(UBound(acat) - 1)

    Sheets("TBL").Select
    Range("B2").Resize(UBound(acat, 2), UBound(acat, 1)) = Application.Transpose(acat)
End Sub
```

Comment: `acat` is one-dimensional. The last line treats it as two-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line to this:

```
Range("B2").Resize(UBound(acat)) = Application.Transpose(acat)
```